# ¿Cómo llamar a una función usando un if con dos condiciones?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Necesito llamar una función en mi javascript al cumplir dos condiciones, pero la verdad no se como, pues una de ellas llamará a una función en una clase de un archivo externo `PHP`, y la otra llamará a otra función de la misma clase.
La función está bien, pero al agregar el `if` no muestra el resultado, es decir, no hace nada.
Les dejo lo que tengo, pero realmente no se si se deba ser así.

```
<script >
$(document).ready(function(){
   //nombre_inci es un select, en donde --Todas las Causas-- es un valor estatico
   //el resto de valores se trae de la BD 
   //Buscar es un boton 


   if ($("#Buscar").click && nombre_inci==="--Todas las Causas--"){

    (function(){

    var parametros = {

    "fecha_rin" : $("#fecha_rin").val(),
    "fecha2_rin" : $("#fecha2_rin").val(),
    "operacion":"mostrar_informe"

    };

     $.ajax({
            data:  parametros,
            url:   'controlador_incidentes.php',
            type:  'post',
            async:false,

           beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");


                    },
            success: function (response) {
                     //alert(response);


                        $("#datos").html(response);



            }

    });

});}


   //--------------------------------------------------------


 $("#tabla tbody").on('click','.detalles',function(){

/* alert($(this).attr("id_rin"));
 var id_rin=$(this).attr("id_rin");
 location.href="detalle_incidentes.php?nro="+ id_rin +"";*/

  });


  });
```

---

Lo deje de esta forma, pero no funciona, no se si te referias a esto.

```
   $("#Buscar").click(function(){

    if(nombre_inci==="--Todas las Causas--"){

    var parametros = {

    "fecha_rin" : $("#fecha_rin").val(),
    "fecha2_rin" : $("#fecha2_rin").val(),
    "operacion":"mostrar_informe"

    };

     $.ajax({
            data:  parametros,
            url:   'controlador_incidentes.php',
            type:  'post',
            async:false,

           beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");


                    },
            success: function (response) {
                     //alert(response);


                        $("#datos").html(response);



            }

    });

    }
  });
```

Comment: cuales son las dos condiciones? esta $("#Buscar").click && nombre_inci==="--Todas las Causas--"??

Comment: De momento solo he agregado esa condicion, que utiliza dos parametros, el "Buscar" que es un boton, y "--Todas las Causas--" que es un select, mi idea es que la otra condicion sea "Buscar" y "un valor x del select" que utilizare para darle un valor al Where de mi consulta que esta en un archivo externo, pero este if solo no me funciona, por lo qque aun no e agregado la otra condición

Comment: En general, no se si la sintaxis del if esta bien para este caso.......

Comment: La verdad que no se. Pero podrías solucionar que dentro de tu evento click, tengas todas las condiciones necesarias. Así solucionarías.

Answer (score 1):

Hace lo siguiente. Dentro de tu evento click, pone las condiciones que quieras que se cumplan. En caso que no haga no va a ejecutar tu código.

Ejemplo:

```
evento click(){
    if(condicion1 && condicion1){
        // hacer proceso
    }
}
```

o

```
evento click(){
    if(condicion1){
        // hacer proceso
    }
}
```

Ya dependerá de como quisieras hacer. Lo anterior es solo la lógica. La idea que dentro de tu bloque del evento click coloques todas las condiciones que quieras.
}

Comment: en donde colocaste hacer proceso, deberia ir toda la función?

Comment: Deberías de poner lo que queres que haga si cumple la condición de nombre_inci==="--Todas las Causas--". Se entiende??

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente, lo hice así gracias a la ayuda de programadores Chile, lo dejo por si a alguien le sirve en el futuro :

```
<script >
$(document).ready(function(){
              //funcion para eliminar el producto de la factura 
   $("#Buscar").click(function(){


    var id_inci = $('#id_inci option:selected').val();

    if(id_inci === '--Todas las Causas--'){

    var parametros = {

    "fecha_rin" : $("#fecha_rin").val(),
            "fecha2_rin" : $("#fecha2_rin").val(),
    "operacion":"mostrar_informe"

    };

     $.ajax({
            data:  parametros,
            url:   'controlador_incidentes.php',
            type:  'post',
            async:false,

           beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");


                    },
            success: function (response) {
                     //alert(response);


                        $("#datos").html(response);



            }

    });

    }

     else {    

        var parametros = {

    "fecha_rin" : $("#fecha_rin").val(),
            "fecha2_rin" : $("#fecha2_rin").val(),
            "id_inci" : $("#id_inci").val(),
    "operacion":"mostrar_informe2"

    };

     $.ajax({
            data:  parametros,
            url:   'controlador_incidentes.php',
            type:  'post',
            async:false,

           beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");


                    },
            success: function (response) {
                     //alert(response);
                        $("#datos").html(response);



            }

    });
     }

  });



 $("#tabla tbody").on('click','.detalles',function(){

/* alert($(this).attr("id_rin"));
 var id_rin=$(this).attr("id_rin");
 location.href="detalle_incidentes.php?nro="+ id_rin +"";*/

  });


});









</script>
```